# How can I make atoi work in my ADS project?

Tags: c, arm, ctype

I want to use `atoi` function in my program, but I found it not working.

```
#include <ctype.h>
int value;
value=atoi(buf);
```

`char buf` points to "1000" or something like, terminated by `\0`. I have checked it.
But the value evaluates always to zero. I have tried `strtol()`, but I get the same error.

1. My ADS (ARM Developer Suit) is v1.2 (s3c2440). I can find the libs in armlib path (c_t_xx.l).
2. I use `axd` debug mode, so I can trace my code. I found `"bl

   __rt_ctype_table"`, so I think asm code linked right.

Please give any advice to fix this issue.

Comment: Your buffer doesn't contain 1000, then.

Comment: `atio` is in `stdlib.h`, and could you give us a demonstration?

Comment: Where does buf come from in the first place? If you declare it and that's it the values in that buffer are just random.

Comment: thanks. buf has no error(debug in axd).Cause no OS work(on  ucOSII),demonstration not so easy. maybe those use ADS and write code for arm (S3C2440) will give useful helps. by the way   strtol(buf,NULL,10) has same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARM might have a problem with string functions, you haven't mentioned whether it returns a value and it's incorrect (i heard it's a bug and it's better you should write the function on your own) or there is no value at all.
anyway look at the arm article about it i think it's the solution - [ARM article about string functions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3536.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        int i;
        char buff[5] = "1000\0";
        i=atoi(buff);
        printf("i=%d\n", i); 
        return 0;
}

#./a.out
#i=1000
```

Comment: yes ,this code works fine in any linux platform,but in my arm platform (usOSII) with ads as compiler.it not works any more.

Comment: make sure you have taken of the following [link] (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3536.html) ;